# Пропала подсветка синтаксиса php VS Code

Tags: php, синтаксис, visual-studio-code

Проблема возникает уже второй раз. В первый раз все нормализовалось само, после переустановки. Сейчас же не помогает. Пробовал и временные папки удалять из `AppData`, но результат нулевой. У гугла спрашивал, ничего толкового не говорит. Файлы `xml`, `js`, `html` подсвечиваются, расширений нет, их удалил.

[image: Нет подсветки синтаксиса]

Comment: В правом нижнем углу (левее звоночка и рожицы) языковой режим PHP выбран?

Comment: Как не странно там определяется как "обычный текст".

Comment: На php переключите, попробуйте, а потом в том же выпадающем меню потыкайте по автообнаруженю, сопоставлению, параметрам.

Comment: я про бывал это изначально. там нет ни намека на  `php`. он предлагает из маркета скачать плагины для работы в форматом `.php`.